# How to detect unsecured wifi network from iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, network-programming, wifi

I would like to detect the presence of unsecured wifi network in my app. Is there any public iOS API available to achieve the same?

Comment: Why closing or down voting? Seems to be a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: There's nothing like unsecured wifi network! All connections are unsecured if you don't use https connection to your webservice and/or don't encrypt sensitive data! Give some more information about what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented API to get that information. If you application needs to send and receive sensitive data across the network, you should generally assume that no connection is secured.

Comment: ... and therefore not bother sending any sensitive data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use an SSL connection for your web service. Then the data that leaves will be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the stumbler application and in particular the [MSNetworkDetailsView](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/source/browse/trunk/Stumbler/MSNetworkDetailsView.m) class, it gives the level of detail that you need.