# iOS detect connection to unsecured Wi-fi

Tags: ios, security, network-programming, wifi

I know, that similar question has been already [asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559252/how-to-detect-unsecured-wifi-network-from-ios-app), but it's pretty old, and doesn't provide the way to solve the problem using public API, only the private one.

At the same time, there are apps in App Store which displays such information, for example [McAfee Security](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mobile-security-privacy-app/id724596345):

[image: McAfee detecting unsecured Wifi]

This means, that there must be a public API acceptable by Apple to solve this task.
I have searched in iOS frameworks documentation and on the web quite intensively, but no luck.
Could anybody give me a clue of how they do this?

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: That apps are displaying this information does not necessarily means there is an public API by Apple. I would assume that those apps send the current Wifi data to a server on the net that has a Wifi database on all known Wifis (like wigle.net). Such a database can also contain the info which security mode each Wifi uses. Of course such a system will not work 100% reliable, however for the use-case in the screen-shot a false-negative (Wifi shown as insecure but it is secure) is not a big problem.

Comment: Hi @Robert, thank you for the response.  I was thinking about such case, using some 3rd party API to get information about the Wifi point I'm connecting to, because Apple exposes BSSID. I was thinking maybe I'm missing something. Besides wiggle.net, do you know any other Wifi database provider?

Comment: Sorry I don't know other Wifi databases. But when I search Google for `wifi world database SSID` I get a lot of results of potential databases.

Comment: I have made such a research indeed, and found that only wigle.net provides an API suitable for my problem. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this?